# Login button is not working on mobile wherease it's working properly on emulator, flutter

Tags: flutter, networking, mobile, android-emulator

I have created an app which is working properly on emulator, successfully logged in, api's are working perfectly too. but when i run the app on mobile , my login button is not working.

i have used 8000 port on backend and on api and 127.0.0.1 ip address.

my login api looks like  http://127.0.0.1:8000/login

here are the logs when i enter username and password and click on login button .

```
SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 45304
```

please help how can i fix it.

Comment: I don't think the problem with the text fields. please confirm, are you able to access your machine in your device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**10.0.2.2** is ip address which will work **only for your emulator**, it's like **127.0.0.1** on computer.

When you want to access localhost from your phone, you have to find your pc's local ip address. You can read how to do it in this article: https://dev.to/tusharsadhwani/connecting-android-apps-to-localhost-simplified-57lm

Comment: hi, it's not working, when i do debugging it works, like when i click on login button it should go to dahsboard screen so when i run my project on debugging control goes to dashboard file after click on login button, but my phone is still on login screen